# What does this awk script do?

Tags: awk

What does this do?

```
( awk '{ if (NR > 1) print prev " " $1; prev = $1; }' file)
```

Comment: FWIW `print prev " " $1` should be `print prev, $1` to use the value of `OFS` rather than hard-coding the same value.

Comment: Also FWIW there is no need for the `(` ... `)` subshell around the command

Answer (score 5):

That is an `awk` script. [Awk is a programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) that is particularly good at dealing with field-separated data. The script itself is quite straighforward:

- `if (NR > 1)`: `NR` is a special `awk` variable and holds the line number of the current input line. So this means "if the current line number is greater than 1", in other words "for every line except the first line".
- `print prev " " $1;`: like `NR`, `$1` is also a special variable that holds the first field of this line. Fields are defined by whitespace (by default, you can change that with `-F`), so given a line like `foo bar`, `$1` will be `foo` and `$2` will be `bar`. Therefore, this will print the value of the variable `prev` (see next point) followed by a space (`" "`) and then the first field of the current line.
- `prev = $1;`: save the first field of this line in the variable `prev`. So when we process the next line, `prev` will have the 1st field of the previous line.

To see what it does, you can try it on test input. For example, use `seq 5` which prints the numbers from 1 to 5:

```
$ seq 5
1
2
3
4
5
$ seq 5 | awk '{ if (NR > 1) print prev " " $1; prev = $1; }'
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

As you can see above, the awk script simply prints the first field of the previous line and then the first field of the current line.

Comment: This answer would probably be a little better if your example had more fields on each line so you could show that they are removed by the script.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I don't know, what makes you think the OP's file has more than one field? We haven't been given any detail so I did what I could with the information provided. To be honest, the likeliest scenario I can think of is that the file only has one field per line, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that input file is space delimited file. Here the given code will read entire file and output only value of first column in a single row.

For example `input.txt` is as under:-

```
AAA 4443
BBB 5595
CCC 4949
DDD 4434
```

The `awk` script will output the following

```
AAA BBB
BBB CCC
CCC DDD
DDD
```

When first line is read, it will store first column of first line, i.e. AAA to variable `prev`. When 2nd line is read, it will print value of prev, i.e `AAA` and then first column of 2nd line, so it will become `AAA BBB`. Now it will store `BBB` in the variable `prev`. When 3rd line is read, it will print `BBB CCC`. When 4th line is read, it will print `CCC DDD`.

Comment: With your sample input the `awk` program doesn't produce the output you show

Comment: Yes, I have corrected

Comment: It only prints the plain `DDD` if there's a blank line at the end of your input file